# How can I make an iPhone OS 2.2 project with XCode 3.1.3?

Tags: iphone, xcode

For some reason, after installing the iPhone OS 3.0 SDK, I have no option anymore to create a 2.2 project. I don't want to develop for 3.0 because I target iPod touch, not iPhone. iPod touch users don't upgrade for 10 dollars so likely.

Xcode creates projects with OS 3.0, and there is no option to switch to 2.2 SDK. Although for my existing projects I still can use 2.2 SDK in XCode.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project is not really tied to an iPhone OS release, it's the "Base SDK" setting in your project. This is by default 3.0 in the new SDK.

To use an older OS, open the project settings (double click on the blue project icon in the Groups & Files section in the project window). Select the Build tab and chose another Base SDK in the Architectures section.